# Netbeans auto generate entitiy from database every database tables change

Tags: oracle, netbeans

We are developing our project using `Netbeans` and `Oracle database` with `jpa`.

When we change something in database, we must regenerate entity from database.

How can we do auto-generate changed `entity` file ?